# Why Strange Answers Java?

Tags: java

I have following code

```
int num1 = 8;
int num2 = 5;

double ans = num1/num2;

System.out.println(ans); // result is 1.0
```

why i am getting `1.0` in `ans` where it should be `1.6` ?

Comment: Change int to double and it will work :)

Comment: Ahhh.. yes it does. but why ?

Comment: Have you done any prior research? For example tried to read **anything** about the nature of the primitive data types that you are using?

Comment: I recommend reading this very closely: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Obvious homework question, yes this board is for people of all levels but please do some basic research before posting.

Answer (score 5):

No, it not should be `1.6`

Here how it is complied

> int / int -> result int.

i.e. `8/5 = 1`

then int value assigned to double.

> int -> double  // is 1.0

if you use this :

```
double ans =(double) num1/num2;
```

this will give `1.6` because `num1` will be considered as double and

```
double / int -> result double.
```